# AWK- script which lists number and weight of all files created in certain month

Tags: linux, awk, command-line, files, directory

I need to write a script in AWK which will count all the files and their weight in "/home" directory from all the months and display the list in terminal.
The output should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you an a system with a filesystem which keeps track of the birth time of a file? Some common filesystems does not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote script in awk which uses system commands `ls` to list files and `stat` to get info about file. After that script will print number of files and size in bytes.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f


BEGIN {
    dir = "/home/matej"   #chnage default directory

    if(ARGC == 2){   #check for command line arguments
        dir = ARGV[1]
    }
    printf("Listing directory: %s\n", dir)


    cmd = "ls " dir

    m_names[1] = "January"
    m_names[2] = "February"
    m_names[3] = "March"
    m_names[4] = "April"
    m_names[5] = "May"
    m_names[6] = "June"
    m_names[7] = "July"
    m_names[8] = "August"
    m_names[9] = "September"
    m_names[10] = "October"
    m_names[11] = "November"
    m_names[12] = "December"


    while((cmd | getline filename) > 0 ){
        "stat --printf=\"%Y %s\" \"" dir "/" filename "\"" | getline info   #use %W instead of %Y if your system supports date of birth
        #FS = " "
        split(info, arr, " ")
        time = arr[1]
        size = arr[2]

        month = strftime("%m", time) + 0   #+ 0 is for converting string to int and removein first 0

        months[month] = months[month] + 1
        sizes[month] = sizes[month] + size
    } 
    close(cmd)

    #pretty print
    printf("%-11s %-20.18s %s\n", "Month", "Number of files", "Total size of files (in bytes)")
    for(a = 1; a <= 12; a ++){
        printf("%-9s:   %-20s %s\n", m_names[a], months[a], sizes[a])
    }

}
```

Modify two things in this script:

- `dir = "/home/matej/"` change your default directory
- `"stat --printf=\"%Y %s\" \"" dir filename "\"" | getline info` use %W instead of %Y if your system supports time of birth

To run script:

- `chmod +x script.awk`
- `./script.awk`or with argument `./script.awk /home/user`

Output in my system looks like:

```
Listing directory: /home/matej
month       number of files      total size of files
January  :   7                    163860
February :   1                    4096
March    :   1                    4096
April    :   1                    764
May      :   1                    4096
June     :   3                    12288
July     :   2                    13142852623
August   :   2                    8192
September:   1                    16
October  :   8                    10975459334
November :   4                    44067
December :   10                   49152
```